PIC18F25K80 Sleep Mode
I've been working on a project with PIC18F25K80 MCU for a while. My main purpose is to collect some sensor data based on user-defined intervals(like 1min) and since this is a battery-powered application I'm using sleep mode with WDT. The problem here is the accuracy of WDT is very low (+-15%) and I need to collect sensor measurements in a high-temp environment up to 125C. I'm using a 16MHz external XTAL for a primary system clock and wondering if there is a better/accurate way to use it for sleep mode instead WDT?
Although the nominal WDT period is 2048ms (with 1:512 prescaler), it's 2064ms based on my measurements. I can't tune that since OSCTUNE register only tunes HF/MF-INTOSC and WDT uses LF-INTOSC.

Consider connecting a 32KHz crystal to the secondary oscillator pins.  A timer running from that oscillator will consume very little power, and can wake the processor from sleep.

I agree that this is the most appropriate solution, thanks for the comment! Then I'll continue using a 16Mhz external XTAL as a primary system clock and add 32kHz XTAL as a secondary system clock for sleep mode.
